# Cannot import MDTextField from Kivy

Tags: python, debugging, kivy

i'm trying to build an app using Kivymd and the only one package that is not working for me is the following:

```
from kivy.uix.textfield import MDTextField
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtHAn.png)

i tried updating Kivy and Kivymd and restarting the kernel
i'm using python 3.9

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to import [`MDTextField`](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/building-a-simple-application-using-kivymd-in-python/amp/) from the wrong module. you should import it from `kivymd.uix.textfield` instead of `kivy.uix.textfield`.

**Correct Import**

```
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
```

Comment: it was that obvious yet i was blind

Comment: @Grizzly then accept it as an answer.